# Varnish probes and logs

Tags: nginx, logging, varnish, probe

I have a LNMP stack with Varnish in front.
I have a probe with Varnish and it checks every seconds if the site is running.

It works good but I don't want to log those probes.

Does someone know please how to disable only that log?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `nginx.conf` put the following inside `http { ... }` block:

```
map "$request_method:$request_uri:$remote_addr" $loggable {
    "HEAD:/:127.0.0.1" 0;
    default 1;    
}
```

Find your `access_log` directive and add the `if` condition to it like so:

```
access_log /path/to/access.log combined if=$loggable;
```

What this does, is logs requests conditionally: a `HEAD` request to `/` made by localhost, will not be logged. Everything else is logged as usual.

Naturally, you will have to adjust `"HEAD:/:127.0.0.1"` if your probe uses different request method, resource or if Varnish is not on the same machine, e.g. `"GET:/healthcheck:1.2.3.4"` will not log `GET` requests to `/healthcheck` by `1.2.3.4`.